# Why toRefs is not working as expected in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I have created a custom hook `useDialog()`, where I return a `params` object which is wrapped inside a `computed` function.

```
// useDialog hook
  ...
  params = computed(() => something(dependingOnRef));
  ...
```

```
// script
setup() {
   ...
   const { params } = useDialog();
   ...
   
   return {
      params,
   }
}
```

```
// template

<div>{{ JSON.stringify( { params } ) }} </div>
```

Everything works as expected. Once I change `dependingOnRef` value, the params get updated and the view changes.

BUT !!

when I use `toRefs` to destruct / spread the `params` object, I do not have the same reactivity.

For example:

```
// script
setup() {
   ...
   const { params } = useDialog();
   const { name } = toRefs(params);
   ...
   
   return {
      params,
      name,
   }
}
```

```
// template

<div>{{ JSON.stringify( { params }) }} </div>
<div>{{ JSON.stringify( { name }) }} </div>
```

In my view I get:

```
{"params":{"id":9,"name":"Some name"}}
```

but an empty object for { name }

```
{}
```

Why is this happening ? Shouldn't the view also be reactive to `name` property of `params` object ?

Comment: what about `const { params } = useDialog();... return { params, ...toRefs(params) }` and `<div>{{ JSON.stringify( { name }) }} </div>` but I think that `toRefs` works only with `reactive` properties not computed